# Flutter Desktop (Linux): Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:46853/1w9LvJSt37I=/

Tags: linux, flutter-desktop

I'm trying to run Flutter Desktop for Linux on **vscode** but it gives me this message:

```
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:46853/1w9LvJSt37I=/
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have manually installed my Flutter SDK. and my `flutter doctor` says everything is ok:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.26.0-1.0.pre, on Linux, locale pt_PT.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• No issues found!
```

What may be the source of this issue?

Obs: It only happens when I launch via vscode, works well if I run via terminal `flutter run`.

Comment: This has been filed under: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73611